# Detect Empty Columns in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have inherited a project where the customer has hundreds of DB tables, within those tables are up to 450 columns, and 500k rows of data. I am trying to detect columns that are completely empty so that a great purged from the DB Tables and within their ERP system can proceed.

The only query example I could find was this:

```
SELECT * FROM `billing`.`users` WHERE
coalesce(`id`, `name`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `email`, `alt_email`)
IS NULL
```

However, this returns all an AND statement basically looking across all columns that are null together. I only want to find those columns that are completely empty.

Comment: Your query detects **rows** with all columns of NULL, not **columns** of NULL over a table... and it will find **nothing** if at least one NOT NULL column is present in the table.